# Working with modalities (sensor data) with different frequencies

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, sensor-data

- Accelerometer data: 119 Hz.
- Gyroscope data: 119 Hz.
- Magnetometer data: 20 Hz.

I would like to build a 2D-CNN. I have sensors with different sampling rates. Rather than extracting a feature, how I can feed my data with different sampling rates to CNN?

Comment: I am not a neural net person, so this is wild spit-balling, but perhaps you could pre-condition the data streams from each device with it's own separate smoothing filter, and then feed your CNN using identical sampling rates from the smoothed signals?

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. This seems like a really good idea. Just did a quick search, regarding filters, I have come across with low-pass filters etc. I do not know about signal filtering, so I will have a look.